# MVC3 globalization: need global filter before model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, globalization

Currently, I have a global filter called `GlobalizationFilter` that checks the route values, cookies and browser languages header to determine the correct culture settings for the request:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    // determine cultureInfo
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
}
```

It all works, but the model binding process seems to occur before the global filters, and so the model binder doesn't take the culture settings into account.

This leads to problems with interpreting double values, `DateTime` values etc.

I could move the culture detection code to other locations, but I don't like any of my options:

- Application's `BeginRequest` event. At this point of time the routing hasn't occurred, so I'll have to manually fish out the `/en-US/` culture token from the URL. This in unacceptable.
- Controller's `Initialize()` method. This will force me to write a base class for all my controllers, and inherit the existing controllers from it. I don't like this, but I'll opt for this solution if nothing better comes up.

Ideally, I want to find some way to inject my code between the "routing complete" and "model binding starts" events, but I found nothing in MSDN / Google on this.

Or maybe there's some other way to handle MVC3 globalization that I'm unaware of?

Thanks in advance for any contribution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Extract out the code that determines the culture into a separate component/class. Then create a `ModelBinder` that derives from `DefaultModelBinder` that uses the class to set the culture before calling `BindModel`

```
public class CultureAwareModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        /* code that determines the culture */
        var cultureInfo = CultureHelper.GetCulture(controllerContext.HttpContext);

        //set current thread culture
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

and then register it for the application (in `Application_Start`)

```
// register our own model binder as the default
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CultureAwareModelBinder();
```

Comment: since I'm going to get a custom model binder eventually anyway, it seems the best way. Thanks

Comment: However, setting the request-wide culture in a model binder seems a bit counter-intuitive..

Comment: you could store the culture before hand, set the culture and bind the model and then restore the original culture. A custom model binder is simply one seam in the MVC architecture, you could implement it in other places if you're uncomfortable with the Single Responsibility Principle arguments. For example, you could define your own route handler that sets the culture. Depends on your driving tenets. If testability is important, don't put it somewhere that's going to be hard to test (like `Application_BeginRequest`) :)

Comment: I'm OK with single responsibility, but a _model binder_ setting _culture_ seems strange to me. I guess I'll look up the route handler customization you mentioned

Comment: +1, nothing better comes to my mind at this point, than implementing a culture-aware model binder