# How to get the intermediate portion of string?

Tags: c#

I have a string as under

```
var input= "dbo.xyx.v1.UserDefinedFunction";
```

The desired output will be "xyx.v1";

My attempt is

```
var input = "dbo.xyx.v1.UserDefinedFunction";
var intermediate = input.Split('.').Skip(1);
var res = intermediate.Reverse().Skip(1).Aggregate((a, b) => b + "." + a);
```

works fine..but any other proper and elegant method?

Kindly note that it can be any part(in the example I just showed 4 parts)

e.g.
Input : "dbo.part1.part2.part3.part4.UserDefinedFunction"
Output : "part1.part2.part3.part4"

Comment: If there are more parts, what would be the desired output?

Comment: updated the question...only the inermediate parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   string output= input.Substring(input.IndexOf('.') + 1, 
                  input.LastIndexOf('.') - input.IndexOf('.') - 1);
```

Comment: output is :xyx.v1.U but not xyx.v1

Comment: I think the second `+1` should be changed to `-1`. Anyway, +1 for an efficient solution.

Comment: @priyanka yes, last +1 would be -1. Actually copied that portion from the first argument.

Comment: It could be +1 if it was closed like that: `(input.IndexOf('.') + 1)` BUT anyway you are calculating `input.IndexOf('.')` twice for no reason... and what of cases of only 1 or 0 '.' in the string?

Comment: I thought OP wants the mid part and not the second until last part.

Answer (score 2):

This returns always the mid part of a string which can be one or two parts(acc. to the total part-number).

```
var input = "dbo.xyx.v1.UserDefinedFunction";
string[] tokens = input.Split('.');
int midIndex = (tokens.Length - 1) / 2;
IEnumerable<int> midIndices = midIndex % 2 == 0
    ? new[] { midIndex }
    : new[] { midIndex, midIndex + 1 };
string mid  = string.Join(".", tokens.Where((t, i) => midIndices.Contains(i)));
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/4xHE68)

So in this case it returns `xyx.v1`, for a string `bo.xyx.v1` it returns `v1` since that's the only mid-part.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel: Ah, i haven't seen his edit. So he wants the part without the first and last and not the mid-part.

Comment: I leave the answer, maybe someone else is looking for the mid-part of a string ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use LINQ, you can use `Skip(1).Take(2)` and `string.Join`, like this:

```
var parts = input.Split('.');
var res = string.Join(".", parts.Skip(1).Take(parts.Length-2));
```

If you need to throw away the first and the last parts, then you can use `Substring`, like this:

```
var start = input.IndexOf('.')+1;
var end = input.LastIndexOf('.')-1;
var res = input.Substring(start, end-start+1);
```

Finally, you can use regular expression, like this:

```
var res = Regex.Replace(input, "^[^.]+[.](.+)[.][^.]+$", "$1");
```

Comment: Kindly note that it can be any part(in the example I just showed 4 parts)

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar This implementation does not care how many parts there are in the original: it takes items #2 and #3, and ignores all the rest of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "dbo.xyx.v1.UserDefinedFunction";
var start = input.IndexOf('.');
var end = input.LastIndexOf('.');
string output;
if (start < end)
{
    output = input.Substring(start+1, end-start-1);
}
else
{
    output = input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "dbo.xyx.v1.UserDefinedFunction";
var intermediate = input.Split('.');
var res = string.Join(".", intermediate[1],intermediate[2]);
```

**EDIT:** for any part version

```
var res = string.Join(".", intermediate.Skip(1).Take(intermediate.Length - 2));
```

Comment: Kindly note that it can be any part(in the example I just showed 4 parts)

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar can you make example what exactly you mean?

Comment: updated the question... it should be all intermediate parts(i.e. leaving the first and last part)

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "dbo.xyx.v1.UserDefinedFunction";
var res = string.Join(".", input.Split('.').Skip(1).Take(2));
```

Comment: Kindly note that it can be any part(in the example I just showed 4 parts)

Comment: Kindly note that you can adapt the arguments passed to the `Skip` and `Take` functions to match your requirements. They can even be variables.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Please, help me look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200309/error-message-model-not-picking-language-specific-resource-file Culture setting is not being applied to my viewModel. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it and do:

```
var split = input.Split(".");
var result = String.Join(".", split[1], split[2]);
```

No need for `Skip` or `Take`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest2
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        var ret = "this.is.my.test.string".MySplit(".", new int[] {0,1,4 });//this.is.string

    }
}

public static class Process {
    public static string MySplit(this string Source, string seprator, int[] positionTokeep) {
        var items = Source.Split(seprator.ToCharArray());
        string ret = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < positionTokeep.Length; i++) {
            ret += items[positionTokeep[i]] + seprator;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ret)) {
            ret = ret.Substring(0,ret.Length - seprator.Length);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```