# Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture Vs Accept-Language in ViewModels

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, globalization

**Globalization:** The reason for asking this question is to have a better understanding of how `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` works in relation to properties and error messages in ViewModels and Controllers

I have setup my project and overrides `OnActionExecuting` method of my controllers I have set the language based on user selection stored in cookie.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["lang"];

    string lang = cookie != null ? cookie.Value : "en-US";
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lang);
}
```

Now, after this, checking the `Accept-Language` header in http request being sent by the browser, the user changes was not reflected - value is still "en-US". It makes me feel that these two are not dependent.

I have also moved the code to Global.asax but it's the same effect. Been on since yesterday.

The `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` setting affects texts on page but not error messages or properties from ViewModel annotations. But when the `Accept-Language` is changed from the browser, then the error messages are picked from the right resourse files.

- Is it possible to manipulate the `Accept-Language` header? - this seems to be read-only
- *Main Question*: how does the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` works? It seems to be what most examples/articles/blogs etc. on the internet use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get globalization right on a public site with ASP.NET MVC, I recommend the following:

- **Use (a fragment of) the URL to determine the culture**, not a cookie. Otherwise it will not be possible to link to a page in a pre-defined language, and search engines will have trouble indexing your content.
- Browser preferences can be used to *redirect* to the appropriate language on first visit (for example, when calling the homepage *without* any URL fragment: www.mysite.com redirects to www.mysite.com/en-US/ for users with en-US preferences in the browser)
- `OnActionExecuting` is *too late* for culture initialization. I recommend reading [Alex Adamyan's article](http://adamyan.blogspot.ch/2010/07/addition-to-aspnet-mvc-localization.html) about localization in ASP.NET MVC, and implement a **custom route handler** to initialize the UiCulture/Culture. This will also work correctly with Modelbinding (for example, when using resources and attributes on view model classes).

As to your other questions: It doesn't really make sense to modify the `Accept-Language` headers since the client sends them to the server. Even if you could modify them, the client would never know about it.

Comment: Thanks for the url-based suggestion. I know about that but it's not a requirement for now. Checking the link you provided, I moved the logic to `Application_AcquireRequestState` and seems to be working now. Also, thanks for the "it's too late" remarks, that made much sense.

Comment: Concerning my last question, how many threads could exist in such an application. `Thread.CurrentThread` refers to the current, which means there could be many. At what point is each created and why? Thanks.

Comment: `Application_AcquireRequestState` did also not work in some situations (too late for localized error messages when modelbinding), that's why I recommend Alex's approach with the custom RequestHandler. It also feels more _MVC_ than a magic event in global.asax.

Comment: The `CurrentThread` is the thread which executes the current request, and it comes from a [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) managed by ASP.NET.